# Check if a process still exists

Tags: posix

Looking for pros and cons about the getpgid() function(c language)
in addition looking for pros and cons about stat() function
for example:

```
if (stat("/proc/172", &sts) == -1
```

additionally, looking for pros and cons about kill() function
for example:

```
 kill(atoi(argv[1]),0);
```

What are the pros and cons of each method regarding testing whether a process exists

Answer (score 1):

Processes are not part of the C language specification. They are, in fact, strictly a operating system feature.

APIs that identify processes by reused numeric IDs are prone to race conditions, i.e. between the process terminating and a query on the ID being done, a new process with the same ID may have been started. There are of course certain conditions where this is prevented from happening. For example in POSIX between a child process dying and the parent `wait` ing on it, the PID will linger on as a zombie process. However for a robust method to identify processes outside the protections of `wait` semantics process "file" descriptors have been introduced (see `pidfd_open`).

Other operating systems don't use numeric IDs and rely on abstract handles instead (a pedantic observer may point out, that these handles may bijectively map to numerical values, but usually they are not "mere" counters). In such environments handles will not be "recycled" and can be used without concern for race conditions.